# run different pipelines on different column in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, pipeline

I have a file that consists of text messages: 1 line = a message. To clean the messages, I have a pipeline that I can run like this:

```
cat file | ./clean.sh
```

But now, I need to do the same thing on a file where every message is associated to an ID, so my new file is of this form:

```
678 message1
456 message2
479 message3
...
```

The column are tab-separated. But I can't run the clean.sh script on it since the IDs + tabs will be removed by the cleaner (and for some reasons I can't modify the clean.sh script).

How can I create a pipeline that would clean the messages, without modifying the IDs? Or, how can I run a pipeline on a specific column only?

The output I need would be:

```
678 cleaned(message1)
456 cleaned(message2)
479 cleaned(message3)
...
```

EDIT:

what I finally did was using a FIFO special file so that everything remains a pipeline:

```
mkfifo col1 col2
tee > (cut -f1 > col1) > (cut -f2 | ./clean.sh > col2) > /dev/null;
paste -d'\t' col1 col2
```

Comment: You can do this in-place with `awk` or `perl` or similar (though it will likely require running the cleaner once per line at least for simplicity). If you can split the file into columns and then rejoin it that makes things easier (you can split with `awk` or `cut` and join with `paste`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` and `paste`. Easy for tab delimited files.

```
cut -f1 file > file1
cut -f2- file | clean.sh > file2
paste file1 file2 > clean-file
```

For an input stream version, is this cheating?

```
... | | (cat > foo ; paste <(cut -f1 foo) <(cut -f2- foo | ./clean.sh))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I did. I just used FIFO instead of cat into a file, because this would be blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @mob's answer, but using process substitution instead of temporary files:

```
paste $<(cut -f1 file) $<(cut -f2- file | clean.sh)
```

If the input is a stream rather than a file, you can read it line by line and call `clean.sh` on each line:

```
cat file | while read -r num line; do
    echo "$num" "$(echo "$line" | clean.sh)"
done
```

Comment: Thanks mob and Barmar. Yes, this is basically what I want to do. However, is there a way to do something similar when the file with messages is not available, like if I'm given this file on a stream? More specifically, create a script f.sh such as "cat file | ./f.sh" outputs me the cleaned file with IDs?

Comment: I've shown how to do it by reading each line and calling `clean.sh` on it.